# I am trying to combine two pieces of arduino code which uses PIR sensors and NRF and part of the NRF code messes everything up

Tags: arduino

I have made a separate sketch where it is only using the PIR sensors and when one is on it moves a stepper motor and moves it a certain angle.

There is another separate sketch where I move a joystick and through NRF it moves the stepper motor of the other Arduino.

When I add the two sketches together I am trying to use the button to toggle which state it should be in(either joystick mode or sensing mode) but there seems to be a part of the setup which is messing everything up. It works separately but when added together it doesn't work and I don't know why as I am trying to learn Arduino and am quite new at it.

```
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.startListening();
```

this is what is messing stuff up because when I remove this the sensors part of the code works properly but I obviously can't use the NRF.

This is all the code

```
#include <CheapStepper.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const byte address[6] = "00001";

CheapStepper stepper (2,3,4,5);

/*--Recordings of sensor activations--*/
long sensorTime1 = 0;
long sensorTime2 = 0;
long sensorTime3 = 0;

int pirSensor1 = 10;
int pirSensor2 = 9;
int pirSensor3 = 7;

char cCommand = '0';

int current = 1;
int previous = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(pirSensor1, INPUT);
  pinMode(pirSensor2, INPUT);
  pinMode(pirSensor3, INPUT);

 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  /*radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.startListening();*/


}

void loop() {
  /*--Read Transmission--*/
  SensorMode();
  /*char text[32] = "";
  radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));
  if (text[0] != '') {
    cCommand = text[0];
  }*/

  /*--React to Command--*/
  /*if(cCommand == '1'){
    stepper.moveDegreesCCW (5);
    Serial.println(cCommand);
  }

  else if(cCommand == '2'){
    stepper.moveDegreesCW (5);
    Serial.println(cCommand);
  }

  else if(cCommand == '9'){
    Serial.println("sensor mode");
    SensorMode();   //Call sensor method
  }*/
}

void SensorMode() {
  /*--Read Sensor Values--*/
  int sensorValue1 = digitalRead(pirSensor1);
  int sensorValue2 = digitalRead(pirSensor2);
  int sensorValue3 = digitalRead(pirSensor3);

  /*--Times of Active Sensors--*/
  if(sensorValue1 == 1/* && control variable is currently off*/){
    sensorTime1 = millis();
    Serial.println("1");
    Serial.println(sensorTime1);
  }
  if(sensorValue2 == 1){
    sensorTime2 = millis();
    Serial.println("2");
    Serial.println(sensorTime2);
  }
  if(sensorValue3 == 1){
    sensorTime3 = millis();
    Serial.println("3");
    Serial.println(sensorTime3);
  }
 
  /*--Find Most Recent Sensor--*/
  long mostRecent = max (max (sensorTime1, sensorTime2), sensorTime3);   //Find max of the 3 values
 
  previous = current;
  if (sensorTime1 == mostRecent) {
    current = 1;
  } else if (sensorTime2 == mostRecent) {
    current = 2;
  } else if (sensorTime3 == mostRecent) {
    current = 3;
  }

  /*--Move Stepper Motor--*/
  StepperMove();
}

void StepperMove() {  
  if(previous == 1 && current == 1){
  }

  if(previous == 1 && current == 2){
    //stepper.moveDegreesCW (120);
  }

  if(previous == 1 && current == 3){
    //stepper.moveDegreesCW (240);
  }




  if(previous == 2 && current == 1){
    //stepper.moveDegreesCW (240);
  }

  if(previous == 2 && current == 2){
  }

  if(previous == 2 && current == 3){
    //stepper.moveDegreesCW (120);
  }



  if(previous == 3 && current == 1){
    //stepper.moveDegreesCW (120);
  }

  if(previous == 3 && current == 2){
    //stepper.moveDegreesCW (240);
  }

  if(previous == 3 && current == 3){
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, because I don't know all these libraries, but I suspect your pins are colliding.

```
RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
int pirSensor3 = 7;
pinMode(pirSensor3, INPUT);
```

Looks like maybe pin 7 is overloaded.  If this is the case you'll have to resolve this either by changing the library code to use different pins, or give up on some function.  This is the problem with combining libraries, often there are pin overlaps that are hard to resolve without some serious thought or revising the library code.

Comment: I have changed the pin but it still doesn't work?

Comment: The code posted in your question appears unchanged.  Also, you need to read all the library sources and determine which pins are changeable and which are not.  Finally, if you haven't read the datasheet for the Arduino part you're using, you should read that as well.  There is not enough information in your question to diagnose further, and it might be hard to find others who have your exact part and exact peripherals to reproduce your issue.